# Publishing image in Tridion

Tags: publishing, binary, image

### What I did

I created a multimedia component (Image name: demo.png) and published it. I found `demo.png` on presentation server.

In the same component, I changed the image to `demo2.png` and published it. I found `demo2.png` on presentation server but demo.png was missing.

### What I expected

I expected that `demo.png` and `demo2.png` both will be available on the presentation server.

Please help me to understand the flow.

Where is the mapping stored? I will like to see how are they stored because what i understand the engine resolves the images and publish them in package.

I will also like to understand, how the delete is triggered and from where.

Comment: Your edit regards the mapping seems to extend this from the original question so I'd suggest you mark one of the answers below as an answer (or respond as to why they are not suitable) and create a new question - although most of the answer to the second 'part' will be to review the documentation and use the API.

Comment: I agree--the mapping would be good as a separate question. Though most probably won't find the answer without reading all of the documentation and testing both scenarios: implicit and explicit publishing and unpublishing. Frank van Puffelen explains the difference in his [Binary Event Tracker](https://sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/binaryeventtracker.aspx) extension.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This behaviour is normal. 
Tridion keeps a list of all published multimedia components and their actual files on the file system.
If you would change the name of a file in the multimedia component and republish it, it will update this record, and remove any old files, and put the new file in place.

If this wouldn't happen, the server you publish to would be filling up with old (stale) images.
If you wish to publish both demo1.png and demo2.png, then you should create two multimedia components

Comment: And to be honest, I think this is a great feature.

Answer (score 5):

If for any reason you require the same image in the CMS to be published with different names (Example: You are resizing the image, create an additional thumbnail version, etc...) is also possible using an overload of the method RenderedItem.AddBinary where you specify a variantid, so there is no conflict between both published files coming from the same source in the CMS

```
public Binary AddBinary(
    Stream content,
    string filename,
    StructureGroup location,
    string variantId,
    Component relatedComponent,
    string mimeType
)
```